# elastic search aggregation field doesn't work..?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm indexing JSON objects on an elasticsearch index by using elasticsearch python API.

I can't obtain the expected results with multi-token fields following the documentation.

I provide below my body mapping code:

```
body={"mappings":{
        "my_doc": {
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "properties": {
                        "name": {"type": "string"},
                        "value": {"type": "keyword"}
                    }
                },
                "name": {
                    "properties": {
                        "first": {"type": "text"},
                        "last": {"type": "text"}
                    }
                },
                "location": {
                    "properties": {
                        "city": {"type": "text"},
                        "state": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fielddata": True,
                                "fields": {
                                    "raw": {
                                        "type": "string",
                                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                                    }
                                }
                        },
                        "street": {"type": "text"},
                        "postcode": {"type": "text"}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I use this aqg query:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/my_index/_search -d '{
"size": 0,
"aggs": {
    "locations": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "location.state"
        }
    }
  }
}'
```

I obtain tokens, OK
But, when I use the raw field:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/my_index/_search -d '{
"size": 0,
"aggs": {
    "locations": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "location.state.raw"
        }
    }
  }
}'
```

I obtain no buckets.

Any advice?

The final mapping following Lax's Advice:

```
body={"mappings":{
            "my_doc": {
                "properties": {
                    "id": {
                        "properties": {
                            "name": {"type": "string"},
                            "value": {"type": "keyword"}
                        }
                    },
                    "name": {
                        "properties": {
                            "first": {"type": "text"},
                            "last": {"type": "text"}
                        }
                    },
                    "location": {
                        "properties": {
                            "city": {"type": "text"},
                            "state": {
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "fields": {
                                        "keyword": {
                                            "type": "keyword"
                                        }
                                    }
                            },
                            "street": {"type": "text"},
                            "postcode": {"type": "text"}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that mapping remove

```
"index": "not_analyzed
```

And it will work

Comment: Sorry I continue: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [location.state.raw] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note ...

Comment: It will be very useful to you to read the next link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html.      if you have a question feel free to ask

Comment: Thank you Lax!!. Solved following the link.